# Link between a function and its Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+, \mathbb{R})$. It's Laplace transform is well defined for all $\Re(z) \geq 0$. Assume that:
$$ \forall \Re(z) \geq 0,~ \widehat{f}(z) := \int_0^\infty{e^{-zt}f(t) dt} = G(z),$$
where $G$ is an Holomorphic function on $\Re(z) > -1$.

May I deduce that for all real number $\lambda < 1$, $t \mapsto f(t)e^{\lambda t} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+, \mathbb{R})$?

If not, do you have a counterexample?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general. For $\Re(s) > 0$ let $$f(t) = \cases{(-1)^{\textstyle\lfloor e^t \rfloor} \text{ if } t > 0\\ 0 \text{ otherwise}}$$ $$ F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \int_n^{n+1} x^{-s-1}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}}{s}$$
As $n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s} = s n^{-s-1}+O(s(s+1)n^{-s-2})$ the latter series for $F(s)$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > -1$.

But $f(t)e^{-\sigma t}$ is $L^1(\Bbb{R})$ only for $\sigma > 0$.

For $\Re(s) \in (-1,0)$  $$ F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(t)-1/2)e^{-st}dt$$ and the inverse Fourier transform of $F(\sigma+i\omega)$ in the sense of distributions gives $(f(t)-1/2)e^{-\sigma t}$

Comment: That is a very neat example, thanks! Do you know what kind of assumptions should we add on $f$ such that the result holds?

Comment: If $f \ge 0$ then there is a singularity at the abscissa of convergence of its Laplace transform. Otherwise if $\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} F(s)e^{st}ds$ converges say absolutely and $F(s) \to 0$ as $\Im(s) \to \pm \infty$ on a strip then you can move the contour to the right obtaining independence in $\sigma$

Comment: Makes sense for both points! Thanks! Also, how to prove that $\sum_{n \geq 1}{(-1)^n n^{-z}}$ is analytic for $\Re(z)> 0$?

Comment: @Adri I'm confused, I thought $f$ was required to be absolutely integrable?

Comment: @Maxim if you want $f$ to be $L^1$, it suffices to multiply this example by $e^{- \epsilon t }$, with $\epsilon > 0$ small.

Comment: @Adri You're right, this just amounts to shifting the region of convergence by $\epsilon$. So we get an $F(s)$ which extends to an entire function but behaves differently on different vertical lines. Another example would be $\exp(i e^t)$, the transform is entire and tends to zero on $\operatorname{Re} s = 1/2$ but not on $\operatorname{Re} s = -1/2$. Both examples exploit the fact that the Laplace transform integral converges conditionally for $-1 < \operatorname{Re} s \leq 0$.